# The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large. Elasticsearch and JSON

Tags: json, powershell, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to add a JSON file (263 MB) into elasticsearch. I already created a mapping for this file using Kibana, now I am trying to add it into elastic search. I am running this command in PowerShell.

`C:\Users\Khan> Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost:9200/mysofindex/_bulk?pretty" -Method Post -ContentType 'application/x-ndjson' -InFile "output.json"`

but this gives me an error. something like this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost:9200/mysofindex/_bulk?pretty" -Me ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Please tell me how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Did you lookup http error 413? The problem has to do with a limit set on the webserver according to the results i get when looking for this error (something at which the error description hinted)

Comment: I somehow understood the hint, but I do not know, how much is the limit and why is that? how can I solve that? I even saw a suggestion to break my JSON into multiple files of 5 MBs, but I am crawling the data into one file.

Comment: You solve it by increasing the limit. Your webserver has an configuration value for that, you only need to find it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to change the setting `http.max_content_length` in your `elasticsearch.yml`, the default value is 100 mb, you will need to add that setting in your config file with the value you want and restart your elasticsearch nodes.

Comment: This setting does not exist there. I am using elastic 7.3

Comment: It does not exist because it uses the default value of 100 mb, you will need to add the config to your `elasticsearch.yml`, for more settings look into the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/modules-http.html)